# How do I make masking in the first name, middle name,and last name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I make masking in the first name, middle name, and last name? Make masking based on the number of letters in each word in the name.
under the condition :

1. if one word contains 2 letters then there is no masking
2. if there are 3-4 letters then the first two letters will be masked.
3. If there are more 4 letters, the first 2 letters and the last 1 letter will be masked.

Example :

1."Jo Dyne Roger" --> "Jo **ne **ge*"

2."Samantha Summer" --> "**manth* **mme*"

I have tried to calculate the length of one word and after that masking. but I don't know what if there are more than two word

```
function nameMasking(name) { 
 var masking = "";
 var replace = "*";
 for(var i = 0; i < name.length-3; i++){ 
    masking = masking + replace; 
  }
    accountNum = masking + name.substring(name.length+2, name.length);
    return name;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please edit your post and place the code up there, not in the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Regular Expressions.

#### For case 2 (words with 3 or 4 letters):

```
// match 2 letters, then 1 or 2 more letters
var regex1 = /\b\S{2}(\S{1,2})\b/g;
// replace first 2 letters with **, leave the rest
name = name.replace(regex1,"**$1");
```

#### For case 3 (words with 5+ letters):

```
// match 2 letters, then 2 or more letters, then 1 more letter
var regex2 = /\b\S{2}(\S{2,})\S\b/g;
// replace first 2 with **, replace last letter with *, leave the middle
name = name.replace(regex2,"**$1*");
```

#### All together:

```
function mask(name) {
    var regex1 = /\b\S{2}(\S{1,2})\b/g;
    var regex2 = /\b\S{2}(\S{2,})\S\b/g;
    return name.replace(regex1,"**$1").replace(regex2,"**$1*");
}
```

#### Usage:

```
mask("Jo Dyne Roger");    // returns "Jo **ne **ge*"
mask("Samantha Summer");  // returns "**manth* **mme*"
```

#### Explanation:

- `\b` matches word boundaries.
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace characters
- `{2}` tells it to find 2 occurrences, `{1,2}` means 1 or 2, `{2,}` means 2 or more
- `g` at the end is for global (matches all applicable words in the string)
- `$1` in the replacement matches a group captured with parentheses

#### New function based on comments:

```
function mask2(name) {
    // match (first 2 letters), (2 or more middle letters), (last letter)
    var regex = /\b(\S{2})(\S{2,})(\S)\b/g;
    // leave 1st and 3rd groups, but replace letters in second group with stars
    return name.replace(regex, function(m,g1,g2,g3) {
        return g1+g2.replace(/./g,"*")+g3;
    });
}
```

You can do additional replacements for masking 1-4 letter words just like in the first function.

#### Usage:

```
mask2("Steven Harts");   // returns "St***n Ha**s"
mask2("Jo Dyne Roger");  // returns "Jo Dyne Ro**r"
```

Comment: How do I break full name into several separate words like first name, middle name, last name?

Comment: @FajarSyairillah That is not necessary for using this solution, but you could get an array of all words in a string by using `name.split(" ");`

Comment: If in one word there are more than 4 letters then the first 2 letters and 1 last letter are no masking. Example: `Steven Harts`-->`St***n Ha**s`. are you have a suggestion?

Comment: @FajarSyairillah Can you explain what you mean? What do you want it do for 4 or fewer character words?

Comment: @FajarSyairillah I added a function at the end of the answer that will mask `Steven Harts` to `St***n Ha**s`. Currently, it will not mask words 1-4 letters since I'm not sure what you want it do.

Comment: Do a masking on a word that has more than 4 letters. but the first, second and last letters are not. like `Steven ---> St***n` .